# K-MVC client and server side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout-mvc

5 days I spent on problem and can not find an issue.
I use [K-MVC](http://knockoutmvc.com/)
for submit data in my project. Here is simple example: 
1) Controller

```
   public class TechnologyController : KnockoutController
{
     public ActionResult AddTechnology()
    {
        var model=new TechnologyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTechnology(TechnologyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _serviceClient.AddTechnology(viewModel);
            viewModel.SavedSaccessfully = true;
        }
        return Json(viewModel);
    }
}
```

2) Model

```
    public class TechnologyViewModel
{
    public int TechnologyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActual { get; set; }

    public bool SavedSaccessfully { get; set; }
}
```

3) Razor

```
    @using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model Core.ViewDataModel.TechnologyViewModel

@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
    ViewBag.Title = "New technology";
}

@using (ko.If(m => m.SavedSaccessfully))
{
    @ko.Html.Span("NEW TECHNOLOGY SAVED TO DATABASE.")
}

@using (ko.If(m => m.SavedSaccessfully == false))
{
     using (ko.Html.Form("AddTechnology", "Technology", ko.Model))
     {
         <p>@Html.Label("Name: ") @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.Name).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.AfterKeyDown) </p>
         <p>@Html.Label("Active : ")         @ko.Html.CheckBox(m => m.IsActual).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.Change) </p>
</p>
         <p>
            <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Create" />
         </p>
     }
}
@ko.Apply(Model)
```

It is work fine. Then not valid model receives in controller it will not submit. But if model sends back nothing happens. The validation messages does not appear. I tried to put in like standard MVC:

```
using (ko.Html.Form("AddTechnology", "Technology", ko.Model))
 {
     Html.EnableClientValidation();

     <p>@Html.Label("Name: ")            @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.Name, new{name="Name"}).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.AfterKeyDown) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name) </p>
     <p>@Html.Label("Active : ")         @ko.Html.CheckBox(m => m.IsActual).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.Change) </p>

     <p>
        <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Create" />
     </p>
 }
```

But It does not work. Help, please! SOS! ---...---...---... :)

Comment: Have you referenced the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your view/layout? Because together with using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)` it should work...

Comment: Yes, it referenced in _Layout.cshtml

Comment: I think, it doesn't work because real ASP.NET viewModel doesn't updated after receiving JSON object from server. I think, JSON object updates only knockoutJS's viewModel what has been created in "first time" page loading. But I don't know, how to invoke validation manually, after JSON receiving. As you saw, the sending scripts and viewModel creates automatically.

Comment: Hi! Find some solution: 
`code`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.validation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Json2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@ko.Initialize(Model)
<script type="text/javascript">
    viewModel.Name.extend({ required: true });
</script>`code`